# joint probability with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with wind speed (sknt) and visbility (vsby) data in hourly intervals from weather stations. I was able to calculate the joint probability for both wind speed and visibility using this,

```
df1=df.groupby('vsby').size().div(len(df)) 
df2=df.groupby(['vsby', 'sknt']).size().div(len(df)).div(vprob, axis=0, level='vsby')

vsby    sknt    0
0   6.0 15.0    1.000000
1   10.0    0.0 1.000000
2   11.0    7.0 0.500000
3   11.0    16.0    0.500000
4   13.0    12.0    1.000000
5   14.0    3.0 0.500000
6   14.0    4.0 0.250000
7   14.0    12.0    0.250000
8   16.0    0.0 0.099796
9   16.0    2.0 0.209776
10  16.0    3.0 0.173116
11  16.0    4.0 0.134420
12  16.0    5.0 0.175153
13  16.0    6.0 0.024440
14  16.0    7.0 0.032587
15  16.0    8.0 0.018330
16  16.0    9.0 0.024440
17  16.0    10.0    0.024440
18  16.0    11.0    0.026477
19  16.0    12.0    0.016293
20  16.0    13.0    0.014257
21  16.0    14.0    0.008147
22  16.0    15.0    0.008147
23  16.0    16.0    0.004073
24  16.0    17.0    0.004073
25  16.0    18.0    0.002037
```

I am interested in finding the probability of wind speed >= x for all visibility recorded. For example, vsby 16, probability = (0.018330 + 0.024440 + 0.024440 + 0.026477 + 0.016293 + 0.014257 + 0.008147 + 0.008147 + 0.004073 + 0.004073 + 0.002037)

I tried,

```
df2.loc[df2.sknt >= 7, df2.vsby].sum()
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. To select a column using `.loc` it is sufficient to just provide the name.

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.loc[df2['sknt'] >= 7, 'vsby'].sum()
```

Comment: I get when I do this, KeyError: 'sknt'. Thank you for your help nonetheless :)

Comment: @manjarok, try update too (`reset_index`). it might help convert groupby to regular dataframe.

Comment: hi @jp_data_analysis, when I ran it, it gave me a value (247). I am interested in finding the probability for each vsby (6 to 16) with that condition. thank you once again for your help